# jQuery .each help, I want to trim() all the strings in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm splitting a string into an array, then I want to remove the white space around each element. I'm using jQuery. I'm able to do this successfully with 2 arrays but I know it's not correct.  How do I loop thru an array and trim each element so the elements keep that change.  Thanks for any tips. Here is my working code using two array. Please show me the correct way to do this.

```
var arVeh = vehicleText.split("|");
    var cleanArry = new Array();
    $.each(arVeh, function (idx, val) {

        cleanArry.push($.trim(this));

    });
```

Cheers,
~ck in San Diego

Comment: you want to do it more effiently by not declaring the second array??

Comment: yes I would like to only use one array, arVeh

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You don't even really need the idx or val parameters. This appears to work on [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/caAEH/):

```
var cleanVehicles = [];

$.each(vehicleText.split("|"), function(){
    cleanVehicles.push($.trim(this));
});
```

**EDIT**: Now that I've seen what you're really after, try using map:

```
var cleanVehicles = $.map(vehicleText.split("|"), $.trim);
```

Comment: If you look a little closer to his question, he is saying he already knows how to do this.  He wants to take an array and simply strip the whitespace w/o creating another array.

Comment: Saw that right after I posted, and I've updated my answer to use map.

Answer (score 8):

I'm going to suggest not using the overhead of jQuery for a simple for-loop...

```
var arVeh = vehicleText.split("|");

for (var i = 0, l = arVeh.length; i < l; ++i) {
    arVeh[i] = $.trim(arVeh[i]);
});
```

Alternatively, get rid of the whitespace from the beginning, and avoid the need for another loop at all.

```
var arVeh = $.trim(vehicleText).split(/\s*\|\s*/);
```

Comment: As I said on @Jerry's answer - wouldn't that be too easy and make too much sense?

Comment: This is clearly the best answer. People get too obsessed with using jQuery all the time, forgetting that jQuery is just javascript anyways.

Comment: I'm just curious... do you have any numbers for the actual overhead of a $.each?  I prefer to use $.each for the brevity of the syntax and that's more important to me than a (likely) `moderate` performance hit.

Comment: but i suppose when u add the .split() in there it dirties up the clean .each... +1 =)

Comment: @Derek - Really depends on the size of the array. Here's what a simple google search provided: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/06/javascript-for-loop-vs-jquery-each.html

Comment: I'm sure that Nick's alternate solution (without any loops) is definitely going to perform better than any with loops too.

Comment: @charles - absolutely. definitely what I'd recommend doing.  If only I could think of advice faster!!!

Comment: So for an array with 10,000 index's the increase is only 3ms?  It's worth the readable code IMO.

Comment: @Derek - for looping in general, that might be okay, but for this, I would still say not to use the loop at all.

Answer (score 1):

Without 'creating' an array in the javascript code (an array will nevertheless be created in memory)

```
vehicles = $.map(vehicleText.split("|"), function(e,i) { return $.trim(e) });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var my_arr = ['    cats', 'dogs    ', '  what  '];
$.each(my_arr, function (id, val) {
    my_arr[id] = $.trim(val);
});
console.log(my_arr);
```

This will trim the value and set it to the indexed item.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use JQuery. Here is your vanilla solution:

`testArray.map(Function.prototype.call, String.prototype.trim);`

Function.prototype.call calls trim() on each of the elements of the testArray. As simple as that!

Answer (score 0):

```
//a simple function
function trimArray(dirtyArray){
  $.map(dirtyArray.split("|"), function(idx, val){
    return $.trim(this);
  });
}

trimArray(vehicleArray);
```

should do the trick

Or you could use some of the awesome power of javascript and use [array.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype).  I'm still a little new at using the `.prototype` of any object... so this isnt guaranteed to work (but it certainly can be done).

```
Array.prototype.trim = function (){
  $.map(dirtyArray.split("|"), function(idx, val){
    return $.trim(this);
  });
}

someArray.trim()
```

Comment: Yes, he wants a way to easily trim the values of an array.

Comment: @darek , no please see his above comment , his code is working but he wants to do more effeicently , i am not saying your code is bad or so , definetly its nice code

Comment: Yes I saw this on the jQuery site, this works  var foo = [1,2,3];
$.each(foo, function(index, val) {
foo[index] = val+10;
});

Comment: @gov - I think you are wrong... perhaps the OP should clarify

Comment: Depending on where you're using that Array prototype, it can be bad juju. I used a similar prototype (unique) on Array in a Firefox extension, and for some reason, it caused a blank tooltip to pop up whenever the mouse rested on anything. Firefox was not a fan of adding prototypes to Array.

Comment: @Chris - HA! that's crazy... wonder what was causing that?  Thanks for the heads up... That's why i said i'm a noob w/ prototype =P

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just do this?

```
 var arVeh = vehicleText.split("|");

$.each(arVeh, function (idx, val) {

    arVeh[idx] = $.trim(this);

});
```

Comment: But wouldn't that be too easy and make too much sense?

Answer (score 0):

You need these two jQuery functions:
1.) iterate through array element with ability to edit items:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/

2.) remove blank spaces from beginning and end of a string:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

Use them this way:

```
array = $.map(array, function(value) { return value.trim();});
```

Check this JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/L00eyL4x/49/